# .getOutputStream() keeps crashing my application

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to send data from my android application to my server. The server I'm using is EasyPHP. In my onCreate() function, I have:

```
    user_editbox  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username_id);
    phone_editbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phonenum_id);
    submit_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_id);



    submit_button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

               String username = "Gina";
               String phone_number = "2225550000";
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {


                        Log.d(TAG, username);
                        Log.d(TAG, phone_number);
                        if(username != null && phone_number != null)
                        {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Inside " + username);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Inside " + phone_number);

                            try {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Entered try");
                                URL url = new URL("http://localhost/Web%20/Practice/Android%20Login/phpserver.php");
                                Log.d(TAG, "URL given");
                                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);




                                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                                        .appendQueryParameter("Username ", username)
                                        .appendQueryParameter("PhoneNumber ", phone_number );
                                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();


                                OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();    // <--- Problem
                                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                                writer.write(query);
                                writer.flush();
                                writer.close();
                                os.close();
                                urlConnection.connect();

                            }catch(IOException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

The problem arises when the program reaches

```
        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
```

A dialog box appears stating

```
   Unfortunately, Program has stopped
```

I'm trying to understand what could cause the program to crash like this with the highlighted code. The server seems to be running smoothly and the PHP script appears like so:

Any ideas?

Logcat

```
   07-11 22:17:30.118 2645-2645/com.example.czar.connectingtoserver D/MSG: onCreate
   07-11 22:17:30.120 2645-2645/com.example.czar.connectingtoserver D/MSG: onStart
   07-11 22:17:30.122 2645-2645/com.example.czar.connectingtoserver D/MSG: onResume
   07-11 22:19:24.758 2645-2645/com.example.czar.connectingtoserver D/MSG: Clicked
   07-11 22:19:24.758 2645-2645/com.example.czar.connectingtoserver D/MSG: Gina
   07-11 22:19:24.758 2645-2645/com.example.czar.connectingtoserver D/MSG: 2225550000
   07-11 22:19:24.759 2645-2645/com.example.czar.connectingtoserver D/MSG: Inside Gina
   07-11 22:19:24.759 2645-2645/com.example.czar.connectingtoserver D/MSG: Inside 2225550000
   07-11 22:19:24.759 2645-2645/com.example.czar.connectingtoserver D/MSG: Entered try
   07-11 22:19:24.759 2645-2645/com.example.czar.connectingtoserver D/MSG: URL given
   07-11 22:19:24.759 2645-2645/com.example.czar.connectingtoserver D/MSG: Output set to true
   07-11 22:19:24.759 2645-2645/com.example.czar.connectingtoserver D/MSG: String Encoded
```

Comment: Can you edit and add your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

The crashing because there is a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` here. You need put all work with `HttpURLConnection` to a `Thread`.

Comment: I thought all programs usually have atleast one thread running?

Comment: In your case the block in onClick event cann't run on main thread, you need separate it to other thread.